# JavaFX invalid URL or resource not found

Tags: java, image, gradle, javafx

i am having some trouble including images in my JavaFX project. The project stores the resources in the src/main/resources folder and it houses the FXML documents and all the images. The FXML documents load just fine, but the image locations all show null.

My code is as follows...

```
package VennDiagram;


import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View extends Application{
    public static Stage primaryStage;
    public static Scene promptWindow;
    public static Scene refactor;
    public static Scene scene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/views/View.fxml"));
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/views/openingPage.fxml"));
        System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/views/openingPage.css"));
        primaryStage = stage;
        System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/views/newFileButton.png"));
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/View.fxml"));
        Parent root2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/openingPage.fxml"));

        scene = new Scene(root);
        promptWindow = new Scene(root2,1020,580);
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event ->{
            quitProgramAlert.display("Confirm Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?");
            if(!quitProgramAlert.closePressed) {
                event.consume();
            }       
        });

        primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(750);
        primaryStage.setTitle("VennDiagram Creator");
        primaryStage.setScene(promptWindow);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

It gives me an error saying the resource cannot be found.

Additional Details:
The project is built using gradle. I load my FXML files in using the same method as i do for the images.
It works just fine with the the FXML documents.

EDIT: The project structure is shown below...
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: post your project structure.

Comment: try `views` instead of  `/views`. If it doesn't work post project folders structure as advised.

Comment: @c0der - I tried this, it does not seem to work. I updated the question to include the project structure. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @c0der The FXML files all work perfectly, im able to see them properly. its just the images and css files im having trouble with

Comment: Can you show the code of one of the fxml files, where the pngs are being used?

Comment: What's the structure of the output directory from the build (I don't use gradle but I believe by default it is `build/classes`)?

Comment: the Projectstructure seems to be okay. Try this

  `FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(View.class.getClassLoader().getResource("views/View.fxml")); 
Parent root = loader.load();`

Comment: @James_D I have the same issue, the output directory is `build/resources`, and inside it the structure of the `src/main/resources` folder is reproduced